# Problem with using Google Antifactory remote repository

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pip

I'm trying to set up remote repository for PyPi with Google Cloud Artefact registry and access it from RHEL8 using pip. Steps I have done:

- created repository type remote for PyPi in GCP
- created /etc/pip.conf on the target VM with the following content:

```
[global]
index=https://<REGION>-python.pkg.dev/<PROJECT>/pypi-repository
index-url=https://<REGION>-python.pkg.dev/<PROJECT>/pypi-repository
```

installed keyring backend libraries:

```
pip list
....
keyring                               23.4.1
keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth 1.1.2
....
```

Trying to search for tox using pip and facing the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/secretstorage/util.py:23: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Therefore, support for it is deprecated in cryptography. The next release of cryptography will remove support for Python 3.6.
  from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
WARNING: Keyring is skipped due to an exception: 'gi.repository.Secret' object has no attribute 'password_search_sync'
User for <REGION>-python.pkg.dev
```

In other words, it is still asking me for Username and Password, even though, the Keyring is installed and should work, according to Google documentation.

any thoughts?